# Regular Expression to replace comma separated words with question marks

Tags: java, regex, string, string-parsing

I want to replace the following strings:

> chrome, internet explorer, mozlla, opera

or

> john, jack, jill, bill

with

> ?, ?, ?, ?

I need a regular expression for Java which can replace the above string. Find all words and replace with question marks

Comment: Are you saying you want to replace words "chrome", "internet explorer", "mozlla", and "opera" with question marks?

Comment: sorry, edited the question. Please see

Comment: You want to transform a comma- and space-separated list of words into a comma- and space-separated list of question marks? What happens with the list `pink, green, sky blue, yellow`? Does it become `?, ?, ?, ?` or `?, ?, ? ?, ?`?

Comment: Thanks Ted, got my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String output = myString.replaceAll("(chrome|internet|explorer|mozlla|opera)", "?");
```

**[Edit]** You are changing the question faster then I can answer.

To replace any word:

```
String output = myString.replaceAll("\b(\w+)\b", "?");
```

`\b` - first or last character in the word
`\w` - alphanumeric
`+` - one or more repetitions

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain properly. I need a generic replace. Edited the question. Please see

Comment: THANK YOU so much. It works. Can you explain that please... :)

Comment: I was trying ,[.*],  - I thought this should have worked for words in between commas at least. I just ordered the book Regular Expressions Cookbook.